# How to get current custom transactional email template ID

Tags: email-templates, transactional

I'm making some changes on the following file:
**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml**

and what I need is to check if there's a custom trasactional email template used, and if it is, I'd like to get it's ID.
(System > Transactional Emails)

I have no idea how to do this! Could you please help me?

**EDIT : SOLUTION 
(based on Marius suggestions)**

In file addp/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml, after `<sales_email_order_items>...</sales_email_order_items>`
 I added the following code

```
<sales_email_order_items_dupl>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default_duplicate.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default_duplicate.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items_dupl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is not aware of the email template that is calling it.
If your template needs to look differently based on the e-mail, you need to use 2 templates for 2 different emails.
I mean instead of using in both of them

```
 {{layout handle="some_handle_here"}}
```

in both of them, you need to use in the section one something like this:

```
 {{layout handle="some_other_handle_here"}}
```

and create the new layout handle in one of your layout files and use a different template file.

Comment: Right now the template use this handler: {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}

Comment: But if change handler should I create another .phtml file? Can you give me more information?

Comment: @ktsixit. If you create a other handle you need to create a new phtml file also.  Actually clone the `sales_email_order_items` into an other layout handle, and inside it change the reference to `/email/order/items/order/default.phtml` to a new template you create. Again clone the template and do your needed changed.

Comment: please check the question edits. Is that solution correct?

Comment: Seams ok at a first glance. Now you have to use the layout handle in your email template `sales_email_order_items_dupl`: `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items_dupl" order=$order}}`